# Error Update Crawler when using UpdateCrawler from AWS powershell tools

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-glue

I was trying to update the Glue Crawler from a powershell script. But it seems AWS dont like the name, eventhough the crawler name was created by the AWS `Data Lake Formation!`

I want to update only the include path, nothing else one that crawler, so i assume the below JSON request is ok, any idea why i'm getting the error?

```
    # Update Source Schema Discoverer Crawler.
    $crawlername = 'wf_db_snapshot_discoverer_286ef141'
    $includePath = "$($Config.DbName)/dbo/%"

$crawlerUpdateReq = @"
{
   "Name": "$crawlername",
   "Targets": { 
      "JdbcTargets": [ 
         { 
            "Path": "$includePath"
         }
      ]
   }
}
"@

$crawlerUpdateResp = Update-GLUECrawler $crawlerUpdateReq
```

**Log**

```
Updating Crawler...
1 validation error detected: Value '{
   "Name": "wf_db_snapshot_discoverer_286ef141",
   "Targets": {
      "JdbcTargets": [
         {
            "Path": "DB_029/dbo/%"
         }
      ]
   }
}' at 'name' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\u0020-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD\uD800\uDC00-\uDBFF\uDFFF\t]*
1 validation error detected: Value '{
   "Name": "wf_db_snapshot_discoverer_286ef141",
   "Targets": {
      "JdbcTargets": [
         {
            "Path": "DB_029/dbo/%"
         }
      ]
   }
}' at 'name' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\u0020-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD\uD800\uDC00-\uDBFF\uDFFF\t]*
The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular expression pattern: `[\u0020-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD\uD800\uDC00-\uDBFF\uDFFF\t]*` does not allow you to add `new line` characters. The JSON needs to be *minified* before sending to the API endpoint.